# My odds ratio and CI’s are very high, is it still okay to continue and report the results?

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval, spss, odds-ratio

I do my analysis on SPSS and I was doing a ordinal logistic regression to see if  the group they belong in (binary, 2 groups ) predict scores on a likert scale 1-7. Whether one of the groups score fall into a higher category of the likert scale.

However, the odds ratio is very high (it’s like 18) and the confidence interval for the odds ratio is lower CI = 7 and upper CI is 42. Is this due to the fact that the sample sizes is unequal between the 2 groups. Is it still okay report?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you haven't violated any other principles, yes, it is OK.

Wide CIs show up in a lot of published research, even in the most prestigious journals.

Having different sample sizes in the two groups is not, in itself, a violation of any rules. The wide CI could be because the sample size in the smaller group is low, but there are other possibilities too.